# How to add margin padding to toolbar item (Xamarin forms)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using a `ToolbarItem` of `Xamarin.forms`. I want to reduce the space between text and Icon. Is there any custom renderer available to achieve this in android? Or any other solution?

Comment: Secondary toolbar or primary toolbar? Can you please post a screenshot as well?

Comment: please check below code...I put one image and one text...I want to reduce distance between this two image text..
<ToolbarItem Text="{Binding LoginLabel}" Command="{Binding OnLoginClickedCommand}" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="iconexample" Command="{Binding OnLoginClickedCommand}"  Icon="{Binding LoginIcon}" Priority="0" Order="Primary" />

Comment: You could customize the title view of ContentPage .Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar .